# Draytek Vigor 2830n WAN connection dropouts

Tags: router, connection, wide-area-network, slow-connection, draytek

For the last two weeks we have been experiencing terrible connections speeds. When running a speed test it normally starts off OK at around 15Mbps but then drops to 0.7Mbs or below making working almost impossible. Nothing has changed on the router for ages so we bought a cheap one to swapout for testing (as we thought it must be our line in) and it worked much better, it did have slight variances but more like 15Mbps dropping to 10Mbps. Is the hardware done? I'd find that hard to believe... is there anything I can try, run/change etc.

Comment: What did Draytek support say?

Comment: Nothing as of yet, have a ticket open with them. SE often provides better ideas...